# JSF/ Primefaces send two request to update input form and sent PDF back to browser

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, stream

given following jsf page

```
<h:form id="#{cc.clientId}>
    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{controller.property}" required="true"/>
    <p:message for="txt"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.print()}" update="@form" value="Print"/>
</h:form>
```

the controller

```
@Named
public Controller {
     private String property;

     public void setProperty() ...

     public String getProperty() ...

     public void print() {
           org.omnifaces.util.Faces.sendFile("".getBytes(), "file.pdf", true);
     }
}
```

the achievement is:

1. Enter no txt -> error message about required value is shown
2. Enter value in txt -> error message will be removed and PDF will be sent back to browser

what happens:

1. Enter no txt -> error message about required value is shown
2. Enter value in txt -> error message IS NOT REMOVED and PDF is sent back to browser

The reason is clear to me, because just one request has been sent to the server.

So i tried:

```
<h:form id="#{cc.clientId}>
    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{controller.property}" required="true"/>
    <p:message for="txt"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.print()}" update="@form" value="Print">
         <p:ajax event="click" update="@form"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

but still just one request is sent to server.

Sidenote: showing PDF works fine in page, but putting form into  no PDF is shown anymore. But first i am interested in a solution to send two requests.

Thx in advance, markus

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute is evaluated during the validation phase of the jsf, processed on the server. So the input component needs to be re-validated in order to get rid of the message.

I'm not really sure on Primefaces, but looking at the doc it appears that "update" is essentially equivalent to the "render" attribute of f:ajax.

If I understand it correctly using the "process" attribute would submit the designated component for processing to the server and "update" would force a re-render.

So, change the ajax tag to:
`<p:ajax event="click" process="txt" update="txt"/>`

Also, changing the event to a keyup event would give immediate feedback and clear the message right away instead of waiting for the click.

Edit:
One more clarification, the ajax call needs to be moved to the input tag and away from the commandButton.

Comment: thanks, actually this more kind of a workaround, because initially i didn't want to do immediate validation (really wanted to have validation on click right before print). But actually i'll go with this workaround. Thx.